# asyncio.gather() -> TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, proxy, python-asyncio

I have a simple proxy checker where I want to return a list of valid proxies.

```
import asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

async def fetch_proxies(url):
    session = AsyncHTMLSession()
    webpage = await session.get(url) # headers=headers
    await session.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.html.raw_html, 'lxml')
    tag = soup.find('textarea', {'class':'form-control'})
    return tag.text

async def check_valid_proxy(proxy):
    try:
        session = AsyncHTMLSession()
        webpage = await session.get('https://ifconfig.me', proxies = {'https' : proxy})
        await session.close()
        return proxy
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)

async def main():
    url = 'https://free-proxy-list.net'
    proxy_fetch = await fetch_proxies(url)
    proxy_list = proxy_fetch.split('\n')[3:-1]
    tasks = []
    for proxy in proxy_list:
        task = asyncio.create_task(check_valid_proxy(proxy))
        tasks.append(task)
        tasks.append(await asyncio.sleep(.1))
    valid_proxies = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return valid_proxies

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
valid_proxy_list = loop.run_until_complete(main())
print(valid_proxy_list)
```

The code runs fully but when trying to print the resulting list, i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mu0/Documents/python_files/web_automation/mailSpider/proxy.py", line 36, in <module>
    valid_proxy_list = loop.run_until_complete(main())
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mu0/Documents/python_files/web_automation/mailSpider/proxy.py", line 32, in main
    valid_proxies = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/tasks.py", line 817, in gather
    fut = _ensure_future(arg, loop=loop)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/tasks.py", line 664, in _ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
```

and the loop keeps running until I KeyboardInterrupt:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1553, in _shutdown
    atexit_call()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 31, in _python_exit
    t.join()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1112, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1132, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    if lock.acquire(block, timeout):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Im sorry for my abysmal coding but I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. Also, im using AsyncHTMLSession because it is supposed to be part of a larger script which uses this module.

Comment: The first thing you should do is simply delete the line `tasks.append(await asyncio.sleep(.1))`.  That is causing the error since the expression `await asyncio.sleep(.1)` is not a coroutine.  In any case, it's pointless to have a pure time delay running in parallel with other tasks.  I can't see any reason for a time delay in this script.

Answer (score 0):

The create_task function expects a coroutine, but in your case, you're passing the result of await asyncio.sleep(.1), which isn't a coroutine. Instead you need to make sure that you are passing coroutines to asyncio.create_task.

```
tasks = []
for proxy in proxy_list:
    task = asyncio.create_task(check_valid_proxy(proxy))
    tasks.append(task)
    tasks.append(asyncio.sleep(.1))
    valid_proxies = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
return valid_proxies
```

This way, when you call asyncio.gather(*tasks), it correctly gathers a list of coroutines.

Comment: Hi, thank for for the suggestion. Firstly, the asyncio.sleep() function needs to be awaited to aviod a 500 Internal Server Errors and timeouts. To space out the requests I awaited this function. Also, in a different piece of code I awaited a task and it worked fine which is the root of my confusion.